# How to getComputedStyle of sub-element of div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, document, getcomputedstyle

Sorry in advance for the ESL choice of words. What I'm trying to get is the getComputedStyle of an h3 that's adjacent (?) or related (?) to a div which has a specific class (mainBook), while the h3 hasn't got any.

Here's an example of the CSS:

```
.mainBook 
{
     position: absolute;
}   
.mainBook h3
{
     line-height: 120px;
}
```

I know how to getComputedStyle of mainBook:

```
const element = document.querySelector('.mainBook');
const style = getComputedStyle(element);
// and then if I want: style.getPropertyValue("nameOfProperty")
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="mainBook">
        <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

Not sure if this helps but:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.mainBook');
    const style = getComputedStyle(element);
    // and then if I want: style.getPropertyValue("line-height");
    // How do I getComputedStyle the h3?
```

```css
.mainBook 
    {
         position: absolute;
    }   
    .mainBook h3
    {
         line-height: 120px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="mainBook">
            <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
```

But is there any way to do the same but for h3?

Thanks!

Comment: Post relevant HTML and then make all of the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript into a [mcve].

Comment: @zer00ne Done. Hope it is up to the standards as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)**  You can get `h3` element as

```
const element = document.querySelector('.mainBook h3');
```

and get its `lineHeight` from `computedStyle` as:

```
const style = getComputedStyle(element);
let lineHeight = style.lineHeight.
```

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.mainBook h3');
const style = getComputedStyle(element);
console.log(style.lineHeight)
```

```css
.mainBook {
  position: absolute;
}

.mainBook h3 {
  line-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBook">
  <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

**2)** You can also get `h3` element from `mainBook` element as:

```
const mainBookEl = document.querySelector('.mainBook');
const headingEl = mainBookEl.querySelector('h3')
const style = getComputedStyle(headingEl);
const lineHeight = style.lineHeight;
```

```js
const mainBookEl = document.querySelector('.mainBook');
const headingEl = mainBookEl.querySelector('h3')
const style = getComputedStyle(headingEl);
console.log(style.lineHeight)
```

```css
.mainBook {
  position: absolute;
}

.mainBook h3 {
  line-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBook">
  <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! I was almost sure I tried that (querySelector('.mainBook h3')) but I must've done something wrong. Thank you!